# Блокировка вывода в консоль с потоков

Tags: c++, многопоточность

Пишу сейчас свой псевдошутер, в котором есть объект, которым управляю я и другой объект(бот), работающий в отдельном потоке и пытающийся меня убить. Так же у меня имеется реализация выстрелов отдельными потоками (1 выстрел - новый поток). Проблема в том, что почему-то защита lock_guard функции вывода в консоль не работает, из-за чего появляются некие казусы в консоле (показано в скриншоте). Буду признателен за помощь!

[image: Сбой вывода]

Вот код функции вывода:

```
static void Object(const int x, const int y, const char sym) {
    COORD position = { x, y };
    HANDLE hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(hConsole, position);
    std::cout << sym;
}
```

Comment: Приведите [mre]

Comment: @dIm0n, у меня там 400 строк и сокращать некуда абсолютно.

Comment: [mre] - это не сокращённый код проекта, а минимальное вопроизведение проблемы. Вы говорите, что проблема в том, что "почему-то защита lock_guard функции вывода в консоль не работает". Если это так, то достаточно написать код с `lock_guard` и выводом чего-то в консоль, чтобы показать эту проблему. Логика игры тут ни при чём

Comment: @dIm0n, простой код с 'lock_guard' работает без проблем. Загвоздка где-то именно в моём коде.

Comment: Где-то это в этих 5 строках функции? Почему вы так решили?

Comment: @dIm0n, Если бы ) Где-то внутри всего моего кода. Возможно, подход отрисовки у меня где-то неправильный, но обнаружить сам я не смог.

Comment: И вы предлагаете участникам без наличия этого кода узнать, где проблема? Я не понимаю, почему нельзя постепенно удалять части проекта, пока проблема остаётся. Тем самым локализовать проблему и привести [mre]

Comment: @dIm0n,я думаю, может, кто-то сталкивался с подобным и уже знает решение.

Comment: А вы уверены, что вам вообще нужно столько потоков? Одного недостаточно?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, как Вы реализуете, например, выстрелы и регистрацию попаданий?  Как Вы сможете сделать бота, который параллельно вам анализирует ваше местоположение и перемещается по карте, одним потоком?

Comment: @Exodus У вас же управление в реальном времени сделано? Ну делаете цикл (т.н. main loop), который выполняется FPS раз в секунду (30?). В цикле сдвигаете игрока на определенное расстояние, если нажата стрелка, и в том же цикле сдвигаете снаряд на какое-то другое расстояние, и бота на еще какое-то расстояние.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, это абсурд какой-то.

Comment: @Exodus, скорее, абсурд это программировать много потоков

Comment: @Exodus Это нормальная практика. А вот "один тред на один объект" - такого я никогда не видел.

Comment: мне представляется, что тут проблема в смешивании std::cout и winapi вызовов